# How to run timer from 0 to 10 min in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Could you please tell me how to run timer from 0 to 10 min in JavaScript?

Here is my code:

```
var secondsToMinutesAndSeconds = function (time) {
        // Minutes and seconds
        var mins = ~~(time / 60);
        var secs = time % 60;

        // Hours, minutes and seconds
        var hrs = ~~(time / 3600);
        var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
        var secs = time % 60;

        var ret = ""; //OUPUT: HH:MM:SS or MM:SS
        if (hrs > 0) {
            ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
        }

        ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
        ret += "" + secs;
        return ret;
    };
// time given by server 
var uitat = 600;
var jobSessionTime ;

function callAtInterval() {
            if (parseInt(uitat) > 0) {
               uitat = parseInt(uitat) - 1;
                jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(uitat);
              console.log(jobSessionTime)
            } else {
              console.log('=====')

            }
        }
// time given by server 600
       jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(600);
     var stop = setInterval(callAtInterval, 1000);
```

Currently it prints from `10:00` to `00:00` yet
i want it to print from `00:00` to `10:00`.

https://jsbin.com/reqocerefa/3/edit?html,js,console

Comment: What is your issue ? Where does this code come from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var secondsToMinutesAndSeconds = function (time) {
        // Minutes and seconds
        var mins = ~~(time / 60);
        var secs = time % 60;

        // Hours, minutes and seconds
        var hrs = ~~(time / 3600);
        var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
        var secs = time % 60;

        var ret = ""; //OUPUT: HH:MM:SS or MM:SS
        if (hrs > 0) {
            ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
        }

        ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
        ret += "" + secs;
        return ret;
    };
// time given by server 
var uitat = 0;
var jobSessionTime ;

function callAtInterval() {
            if (parseInt(uitat) < 600) {
               uitat = parseInt(uitat) + 1;
                jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(uitat);
              console.log(jobSessionTime)
            } else {
              clearInterval(stop);

            }
        }
// time given by server 600
       jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(0);
     var stop = setInterval(callAtInterval, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var secondsToMinutesAndSeconds = function (time) {
        // Minutes and seconds
        var mins = ~~(time / 60);
        var secs = time % 60;

        // Hours, minutes and seconds
        var hrs = ~~(time / 3600);
        var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
        var secs = time % 60;

        var ret = ""; //OUPUT: HH:MM:SS or MM:SS
        if (hrs > 0) {
            ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
        }

        ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
        ret += "" + secs;
        return ret;
    };
// time given by server 
var uitat = 0;
var jobSessionTime ;

function callAtInterval() {
            if (parseInt(uitat) < 600) {
               uitat = parseInt(uitat) + 1;
                jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(uitat);
              console.log(jobSessionTime)
            } else {
              console.log('=====');

              clearInterval(stop); // stop timer
            }
        }
// time given by server 0
jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(0);
var stop = setInterval(callAtInterval, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You would just make these changes to start at zero and count up to 600 seconds:**

```
// ...
  var uitat = 0; // Change `= 600` to `= 0` to start at 0 seconds
  var jobSessionTime;

  function callAtInterval() {
    if (parseInt(uitat) < 600) { // Change `> 0` to `< 600` to stop at 600 seconds
      uitat = parseInt(uitat) + 1; // Change `- 1` to `+ 1` to count up
// ...
```

---

**Here is the complete code with the changes:**

```js
var secondsToMinutesAndSeconds = function(time) {
  // Minutes and seconds
  var mins = ~~(time / 60);
  var secs = time % 60;

  // Hours, minutes and seconds
  var hrs = ~~(time / 3600);
  var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
  var secs = time % 60;

  var ret = ""; //OUPUT: HH:MM:SS or MM:SS
  if (hrs > 0) {
    ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
  }

  ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
  ret += "" + secs;
  return ret;
};

// time given by server 
var uitat = 0; // Change `= 600` to `= 0` to start at 0 seconds
var jobSessionTime;

function callAtInterval() {
  if (parseInt(uitat) < 600) { // Change `> 0` to `< 600` to stop at 600 seconds
    uitat = parseInt(uitat) + 1; // Change `- 1` to `+ 1` to count up
    jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(uitat);
    console.log(jobSessionTime);
  } else {
    console.log('=====')

  }
}

// time given by server 600
jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(600);
var stop = setInterval(callAtInterval, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with 600 held in a parameter:

```js
var secondsToMinutesAndSeconds = function (time) {
  // Minutes and seconds
  var mins = ~~(time / 60);
  var secs = time % 60;

  // Hours, minutes and seconds
  var hrs = ~~(time / 3600);
  var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
  var secs = time % 60;

  var ret = ""; //OUPUT: HH:MM:SS or MM:SS
  if (hrs > 0) {
   ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
  }

  ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
  ret += "" + secs;
  return ret;
 };
// time given by server 
var uitat = 600;
var current = 0;
var jobSessionTime;

function callAtInterval() {
 if (current < uitat) {
  current += 1;
  jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(current);
   console.log(jobSessionTime)
 } else {
   console.log('=====')
   clearInterval(stop);    
 }
}
     jobSessionTime = secondsToMinutesAndSeconds(0);
     var stop = setInterval(callAtInterval, 1000);
```